# Can't use a python application, which uses the google protocol buffer

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use an application I found on GitHub which records live updates for public transport positions, see the following link to the instructions and application:

https://github.com/mattwigway/gtfsrdb

When I modify the terminal commands to:

```
python gtfsrdb.py run -p https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/Feed/SEQ.pb -d sqlite:///test.db -c
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception occurred in iteration
(<class 'google.protobuf.message.DecodeError'>, 
DecodeError('Unexpected end-group tag.',), 
<traceback object at 0x107d21248>)
```

How do I get this application to record the live feeds from https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the URL:

```
https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/Feed/SEQ.pb
```

This URL doesn't exist -- it returns 404. You can see this by opening it in your browser. The script you are running is probably trying to parse the 404 page HTML as a protobuf, which of course fails.

Perhaps you meant this url:

```
https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/Feed/SEQ
```

Note the lack of `.pb` at the end. I haven't tried `gtfsrdb.py` myself, but this URL appears on the site you linked and appears to return protobuf data.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't resolve the issue, thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 0):

This error appeared for me due to authentication errors. Once I fixed this, the error went away.

Comment: Could you elaborate further?